# Passing Value in ASP.NET Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, parameter-passing

I am developing a web application using asp.net and C#. I have a question

Is there any way for passing values in asp pages without using `QueryString` or `Session` values or `Cookies` or previous page?

Comment: form submits? hidden values? databases? view state? However, we need some code around which you are facing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may see: [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Profile Properties**

> You can use: ASP.NET provides a feature called profile properties,
>   which allows you to store user-specific data. This feature is similar
>   to session state, except that the profile data is not lost when a
>   user's session expires. The profile-properties feature uses an ASP.NET
>   profile, which is stored in a persistent format and associated with an
>   individual user. The ASP.NET profile allows you to easily manage user
>   information without requiring you to create and maintain your own
>   database. In addition, the profile makes the user information
>   available using a strongly typed API that you can access from anywhere
>   in your application. You can store objects of any type in the profile.
>   The ASP.NET profile feature provides a generic storage system that
>   allows you to define and maintain almost any kind of data while still
>   making the data available in a type-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**asp.net cache**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919782%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or  save data from one page in to some `persistent medium` and other page would read from that medium could be `database or xm`l etc.

Answer (score 0):

Beside your requirements(not using `QueryString` or `Session` values or `Cookies`) yes you can use `public` property like

```
public String YourProperty
{
    get
    {
        return "Return What you want to pass";
    }
}
```

Check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article for full code